# Lanching a loading screen in android and displaying till network established

Tags: android

I developed an android application which allows to connect to WIFI after configuration, so it takes time to be done. And I think to a window loading conditioned that starts at the launch of the application and will go away when network configurations are completed.
Please help me to create this loading window.

Comment: what have you tried?  Have you tried listening for any intents (specifically ones to do with the network) to determine the network status?

Comment: Could you clarify what you're looking for, perhaps with a picture? For example, do you want a progress bar/spinner?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  Progess Dialog, start it when your application starts ( onCreate() of your main activity for example ) and end it when your are connected to internet.